# How to view streets in OMNet ++?

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

Usually when integrating SUMO, VEINS and OMNeT ++ is shown in OMNeT ++ the polygons of buildings that are close to the streets, allowing to see the outline of the streets.

However, Manhattan-type models do not have polygons that outline the streets.

Would it be possible using another feature to view the grid of a Manhattan model in OMNeT ++?

Comment: In my project, as I use parked cars, I can change the color of parked vehicles to perceive the road. To change the color of the parked car just use "getParkingState".

Comment: An example code in handlePositionUpdate is: `if (mobility->getParkingState()) {
            findHost()->getDisplayString().setTagArg("i", 1, "darkcyan");
        }`

Comment: You could use TraCI commands to get the streets from SUMO, then use the annotation manager to draw them.

Comment: If you cannot see buildings in the OMNeT++ GUI in some simulations, but can see them in others, most likely these buildings are not known to the simulation. This will be a problem if you care about their impact on radio propagation

Comment: Is it possible to generate polygons in SUMO even without importing a map?

Comment: Yes, this is possible.